# Template media Sonata Media Bundle - Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4

Hola que tal acudo a ustedes ya que estoy atorado con Sonata Media Bundle con Symfony 4.

Ya he configurado todo según la documentación y funciona correctamente, pero el template que se usa para renderizar los botones de "Agregar Imagen" aparecen de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anteriormente he usado el bundle con Symfony 3, y el template que renderiza esta sección aparecía de esta otra manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver es una forma más ordenada y más fácil para el usuario. Sin embargo no he logrado encontrar mi error o que me está faltando.

De antemano gracias a la comunidad.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de mucho indagar y revisar en mi anterior proyecto realizado en Symfony 3.

Me doy cuenta que para lograr que el form sea visible correctamente en vez de colocar así el campo que contiene la imagen:

```
$builder->add('media', 'sonata_media_type', array(
     'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.youtube',
     'context'  => 'default'
));
```

Se debe colocar así, más simple.

```
class OgaUsersAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
    {
        protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
            $formMapper->add('userFirstname', TextType::class)
                       ->add('userImage', ModelListType::class);
    }
```

Ojalá les sirva.

Saludos!!